# Refresh <table> in rails project with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails, jquery etc. 
I created a new Project and everything is working. Now I would like to refresh a HTML Table every few seconds.

My table in the view looks like this:

```
<table>
<% @new.each do |s| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= s.name %></td>
        <td> <%= s.status %> </td>
        <td> <%= s.timeup %> </td>

    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Every few seconds it gets new data and I don't want to refresh the site every time.

If a row get's deleted I would also like to have an animation when the row disappears.

I realy have no idea about Javascript so please explain it for dummys ;)

Answer (score 3):

you can go two ways, Real time table refersh (your going to need something like pusher or private pub) or fixed time refresh(refresh only the table with jquery)

for the first one i recomend you this RailsCasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub

for the second one here is a quick example:

first adapt your controller so it can respond to a js request:

controller:

```
  def show   
    @group = @store.group
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.js
      # format.json { render json: @store }
    end
  end
```

then make an ajax call every X amuont of time:

```
$.ajax({
  type    : 'POST', //Check the type of your request
  url     : "http://localhost:3000/route",   //the route where you can fetch the table 
  data    : { tester : { name : 'boom' } },
  success : function(data) {
              alert(data);          
            },  
});
```

then you need to create your response view:

view.js.erb:

```
$('#table').replaceWith('<%= j render :partial => "layouts/tablepartial"%>');
```

then you do a partial:

_tablepartial.html.erb:

```
<%if @instanceObject%>
    redo table here
<%end%>
```

I know its overwhelming at first, but if you are realy a beginner you should try learning more basic stuff, if you need any help, post it. cheers